# Force C# MongoDB driver to generate "$elemMatch" over dot notation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

The C# MongoDB driver will translate basic array queries into "dot notation", but unfortunately [CosmosDB doesn't support this syntax by default](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/33755596-support-dot-notation-with-mongodb).

I'm currently working around the issue by adding an additional (pointless) condition to my query, which forces the use of `$elemMatch` but I'd prefer to do it at a configuration level if possible.

Eg.

```
collection.Find(c => c.Items.Any(i => i.Status == 1));
```

Will generate the query:

```
{"Items.Status": 1}
```

But I want it to generate:

```
{"Items": { "$elemMatch": { "Status": 1 } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic `Builders` type from MongoDB .NET driver to explicitly build [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) query using your model class, try:

```
var filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Items, item => item.Status == 1);
collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: True, but it's more than I'm trying to avoid needing to communicate the limitation to every developer that works on the codebase.